# why /etc/hosts don't effect to my firefox on Ubuntu 10.04?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hosts-file

I tried to block some hosts to load from them ads and scripts. 
for example in `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1 web-visor.com
0.0.0.0   c1.web-visor.com
```

Why after editing and saving the file, firefox (after restart) still load this sites (not from cache of course)?

My `/etc/host.conf` seems to search previously in hosts file

```
order hosts,bind
multi on
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2):

`host.conf` is obsolete, look in `nsswitch.conf` .

Comment: Do you know how to use it instead of `/etc/hosts`? Because the manual doesn't seem to give even a little hint, and I couldn't find an examples about that. `/etc/hosts` can't supposed to be obsolete until the new one can execute it's functions. From manual I am doubt that it is.

Comment: /etc/host.conf is obsolete, /etc/hosts isn't. nsswitch.conf decides whether and how /etc/hosts is used.

Answer (score 1):

Does your Firefox use proxy?
/etc/hosts SHOULD effect your Firefox (I tested it). What is the result of pinging those addresses?

Comment: How did you test this? In my experience, a proxy overrides `/etc/hosts`.

Comment: If you turn on the feature that intranet addresses should not use proxy, then `/etc/hosts` should no be overridden by the proxy (technically it is not an override, the domain you try to reach will be sent to the proxy, and the proxy will re-resolve it by its own DNS which will return a correct IP).

Answer (score 1):

put www version of domain also in `/etc/hosts`.

```
127.0.0.1 web-visor.com
127.0.0.1 www.web-visor.com
```

It is because firefox tries to resolve `www.web-visor.com` as well.

Comment: This did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
# =============================================================================
# URL: https://ss64.com/osx/fc.html 
#      The ad at the bottom
# Computer: MacBook Pro OSX 10.13.4
# Browser: Firefox Quantum 59.0.2 (64-bit)
# Problem: /etc/hosts was not being observed by browser
# =============================================================================
```

So, I know this post is way old but, for me in "Firefox Quantum"
not being able to use the `host` file was driving me NUTS, I'm way to OCD for this... lol, so before I canned Firefox, I Ran/Fell down the rabbit hole

After scouring thru the web looking for answers, reading blogs forums and potential answers everywhere, yet, still getting nowhere:

I had tried:

1. Reformatting my `/etc/hosts` file

   - Just incase this contained hidden characters
   - Also, Tested host file formatting using:

     - 1 space
     - 4 spaces
     - 1 tab
     - This made no difference to `Chrome`, `Safari` or `Firefox`
2. Also, Tried modifying Firefox's `about:config` Changed

   - `browser.fixup.dns_first_for_single_words` to `True`
   - `network.dns.disablePrefetch` to `True`
   - `network.dns.offline-localhost` to `False`
   - `network.dnsCacheEntries` to `0` (ZERO)
   - `network.dnsCacheExpiration` to `0` (ZERO)
   - `network.dnsCacheExpirationGracePeriod` to `0` (ZERO)

and to no avail (I reverted all the above back to default)

```
# =============================================================================
# FINALLY, I found that you have to change 3 things
# =============================================================================
```

- Navigate to `3 bars > Preferences > General > Scroll to the end > Network Proxy > settings`
- `Configure Proxies to Access the Internet: *CHANGE* Auto-detect proxy settings for this network`

  - I was using `Use System Proxy Settings`

    1. I also found that is you change tracking in preferences & config this hides the box's too in Firefox
- Navigate to `3 bars > Preferences > Privacy & Security > Tracking Protection >`Always`& "Do Not Track" >`Always
  `AND YOU ALSO have to set this in the browser`about:config`
- `privacy.trackingprotection.enabled` To `True`

This hides the error'd out ad's instead of showing the iframe with the blocked content.

I'm so happy right now that I got this workin' I hope this helps someone!